# Image url is correct but gives null response via httpClient request in .net core 2.0 app

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.0 console application where I am downloading images

```
private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<MemoryStream> GetImageData(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        var data = await Client.GetAsync(filename);
        byte[] imageStream = await data.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        return new MemoryStream(imageStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

....
// Some logic
using (MemoryStream imageStream = await ImageUtilities.GetImageData(item))
{
    if (index1 >= 0 && index1 < 2)
    {
        using (var resized = ImageUtilities.ResizeImageWithSameAspectRation(imageStream, 262, 230))
        {
            if (resized != null)
            {
                PropertyRefNo = PropertyRefNo.Replace("#", "-");
                string fileName = PropertyRefNo + "_" + index1 + ".jpeg";

                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(ImageStoragePath + PropertyRefNo))
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ImageStoragePath + PropertyRefNo);

                resized.Save(ImageStoragePath + PropertyRefNo + "\\" + fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Console.WriteLine("Icon: " + fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for some images (`https://www.mylorealestate.com/stuff/property_watermark_images/property_image_9790149681555838146.jpg`), it gives error in `GetImageData` function. Error is enclosed below.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response     
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()     at 
System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()     
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at DubaiRent.Core.ImageUtilities.<GetImageData>d__9.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\Web\App.Core\ImageUtilities.cs:line 247  
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at DubaiRent.Core.Implementation.XmlPropertyManager.<UploadImage>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\Web\App.Core\Implementation\XmlPropertyManager.cs:line 582
```

**Update:**
For this working image URL, it returned null

```
https://watermark.propspace.com/watermark?c_id=1049&l_id=1576257625548605&aid=1464510&id=15189030190082803&wmt=1521113471&image=25_03_2018-15_34_18-1049-fe5df232cafa4c4e0f1a0294418e5660.jpeg
```

[image]

and for remaining images, it return below response

[image]

**Update:** 
[image]

Comment: How does it matter what you do with the image if you cannot download it? Aim for a [mre] and remove unneeded code

Comment: [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }` this doesn't make too much sense. Either don't catch at all or if you want to log the exception here, do so and use `throw` instead of `throw ex`. The Stacktrace will differ.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, actual images are of big size and by downloading and scaling, I am reducing their size.

Comment: @Fildor, let me read the blog and make changes. Thanks

Comment: @JitendraPancholi _"by downloading and scaling, I am reducing their size"_ Yes, but that is irrelevant to the timeout. The size of the image may be relevant, though. About how big are we talking? 100s of MB?

Comment: on an average around 4 MB and i display those images in my website on a listing page. that displays 25 images, so total page size would be 25x4=100 MB which is huge performance issue.
And yes that size is not relevant to above error. I explained this because @CamiloTerevinto asked

Comment: One question: Can you get the images that time out in your app through browser or curl without problems?

Comment: Yes, I even attached one url in question itself That's working in browser but failed via code. I am now trying that blog code.

Comment: @Fildor I updated code and error detail in question. Pls check. It still gives error for some images.

Comment: Aha ... different Error now. Do you have access to server logs? Maybe also try and stick your nose on the line (WireShark, or the like) to see what actually comes back from server.

Comment: Okay. Let me debug it more.. :)

Comment: It returns null for some working image URLs, pls see updated question @Fildor

Comment: Yes, it is null, because the Exception happens inside the Method, that would normally return it. Question is now: Why does it say "The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response" ?

Comment: @Fildor pls check updated question for all other images.

Comment: Mhm, Expected. I suspect that the server for the problematic images, for whatever reason does not return a proper (valid) HTTP response. Have a look at the raw data on the line. If the response is not a valid HTTP, then the problem is with server, not your client.

Comment: You have little or no error handling for when (not if) the server returns an HTML response, you are incorrectly assuming that the server will always return an image.

Comment: @Fildor trying to get that.

Comment: @Kami my concern is not for that. Concern is if URL is correct, then why it gives error. I am trying Fildor's suggestion now.

Comment: @Fildor pls check updated question (last image)

Comment: Nice try. But you'd be better off using some tool like WireShark or Fiddler, so you can really see nicely what the server sent back. In the snippet, you only see that _something_ came back. But alas, Is the number of bytes roughly reasonable if you take a small overhead for HTTP into account?